# ¿Por qué decimos "La puerta 'es' abierta por el camarero" y no 'está'?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugación, cópulas

He encontrado unos ejercicios de ser y estar ([enlace a un pdf](http://www.ecoles.cfwb.be/arapseraing/Cours/Espagnol/8.%20Ser%20y%20estar.pdf)). El numeral 25 del ejercicio número 1 es:

> *Elige entre ser o estar y conjuga.*
>
> La puerta ... (ser/estar) abierta por el camarero.

La respuesta dice que es:

> La puerta **es** abierta por el camarero.

¿Por qué la solución es con *ser*?
¿No es una situación temporal?

Comment: Look at a5 for a hint.

Comment: as mdewey said notice 'abierta' is past participle so that is passive voice. It would be 'estar'' and it would be a temporary situation if it said "la puerta está abierta" (the door is open) but it says (the door is **opened by** the waiter).

Comment: Gracias, lo entiendo.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [Ser and Estar differences in passive voice?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5798/1674). Debate relacionado: [Necesitamos una pregunta canónica sobre ser/estar](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2498/1674). Esta podría ser canónica del _ser/estar en voz pasiva_ si tenemos buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los verbos transitivos ser y estar, son particularmente complicados para quienes aprenden castellano cuando su lengua nativa es el inglés, ya que en este idioma solo hay un verbo transitivo.

El truco es que el castellano hace la distinción de quién realiza la acción del verbo y quién es afectado por esa acción a través de los dos verbos transitivos *ser* y *estar*, que solo transmiten la acción del verbo principal de la oración.

La regla de oro es recordar que los objetos inanimados generalmente *Están** mientras que las personas y en general los seres animados pueden ser o estar por sí mismos cuando sus acciones recaen sobre ellos.
Entonces sí aplica la regla acerca de:

- ser = estado permanente
- estar = estado temporal.

En este caso es importante saber en quién recae la acción del verbo y quién la realiza. Al decir *la puerta está abierta*, en efecto se trata del estado temporal de la puerta.

Sin embargo, al añadir *por el camarero*, tenemos un sujeto animado que realiza la acción sobre la puerta en el tiempo presente de la oración.

Al decir *la puerta es abierta*, necesariamente implica que alguien la está abriendo, ¿quién? En este caso, *el camarero*.

Si no pudiésemos mencionar quién realiza la acción, para que la frase sea correcta podríamos decir "la puerta está siendo abierta" dejando tácito o implícito que hay alguien realizando la acción sobre la puerta.

(* hay excepciones en cuanto al contexto o dominio en el que estamos hablando.  En una discusión sobre la segunda ley de Newton por ejemplo, un objeto inanimado muy bien puede ser quien realiza una acción sobre otro objeto inanimado)

---

The  transitive verbs *ser* and *estar*, are particularly tricky to those learning spanish whose native language is english, because english has only one transitive verb: to be.

The trick is to remember that in spanish we can make a distinction between who carries out the verb's action and who is affected by it, through the transitive verbs *ser* and *estar*.

The rule of thumb is that inanimate objects generally "*estan*" since they can't act out a verb in an of themselves, while on the other hand, animate subjects such as people, animals (and in a real and metaphorical way, nature say a storm or typhoon) can carry out a verb's action in an of themselves, and ALSO be subject o the action of another animate subject in the sentence.

so, while a door can only *estar* abierta by itself, if there is another subject, (el camarero) who is inflicting the verb *abrir* on the door.

If for some reason we could not see or say who is opening the door, we can leave it as an implicit subject, not mentioned in the sentence, but foreshadowed by the presence of both transitive verbs:

"*La puerta esta siendo abierta*" lets us know that someone is opening the door, while not mentioning him explicitly, and it would be absurd to think the door opens by its own will.

There are nuances though, depending on context as always: In a Physics discussion about Newton's 2nd law you may refer to inanimate objects as if they were capable of inflicting actions on another animate objects, much like nature, while being inanimate itself, in certain events is referred to as an animate subject, that can ser or estar by itself.

Comment: los verbos ser y estar son intransitivos

Answer (score 0):

Esto es asi porque se trata de voz pasiva.

**Voz activa:**

El camarero abre la puerta

**Voz pasiva:**

La puerta es abierta por el camarero